# Garbage allocation for Tomcat

Tags: garbage-collection

I am working on application which is receiving high traffic. Each request takes around 100-500ms.
There is no memory leak.
When i enable garbage logging, i can see that when GC happens when i allocate 8 GB memory. 
Log clearly clarify how much memory is reclaimed. But GC triggers stop the world event.

When i compare 8 GB allocation with 4 GB allocation, i find that with 4 GB GC occurs frequently but takes less time than 8 GB, which is expected.

But application response time is variable. For some request it could be higher.

I just want to know what is best deployment for application which receive high traffic.

Is running 2 tomcat with 4 GB is better or one tomcat with 8 GB is better.
Is there any other solution so that Tomcat always send response within time limit

I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to control stop the world event so that my response time is not affected for some of the request.

Comment: Can u add relevant sections of gc logs for 8 gb and 4 gb